MSE of VAR impulse responses in R
I am using the vars library in R. How do I calculate the MSE of the impulse responses I generate with the irf function? The irf function returns the impulse response coefficient matrix and the lower and upper confidence intervals. Is there some other way I could compute the MSE of the impulse responses I generate?

How do you define the MSE of the impulse responses?

@RichardHardy That is what I am trying to understand. If the impulse responses are recovered from iterating the one-step-ahead coefficients of the system y_{t+1} = By_t + \varepsilon _{t+1} where \varepsilon_t \tilde N(0, \sigma), up to the horizon of interest and MSE is basically SSR^2, then that means after iterating to the horizon of interest the MSE is just the square of the residuals of the previous horizons of the target variable?

Did you invent the concept of MSE of the impulse responses yourself, or did you borrow it from somewhere? I cannot recall it.

@RichardHardy I understand now. Thank you for the guidance.

If you understand now, you may answer your own question. This way other users will have access to your answer should they have the same question.
